# Inject list of beans implementing same interface

Tags: java, cdi, quarkus

Supposing I have following interface

```java
public interface Handler {
    void handle(Object o);
}
```

and implementations

```java
public class PrintHandler implements Handler {
    void handle(Object o) {
        System.out.println(o);
    }
}
public class YetAnotherHandler implements Handler {
    void handle(Object o) {
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

I want to inject all `Handler` subclasses into some class

```java
public class Foo {
    private List<Handler> handlers;
}
```

How can I achieve this using Quarkus?

Comment: You can `@Inject Instance<Handler>`, where `Instance` implements `Iterable`. Note that your `Handler` implementations should have a bean defining annotation, such as `@ApplicationScoped`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

All the implementation needs to be marked for @ApplicationScoped like:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class PrintHandler implements Handler {
    public String handle() {
        return "PrintHandler";
    }
}
```

In the class where you want to inject all the implementations, use

```
@Inject
Instance<Handler> handlers;
```

This `Instance` is imported from `javax.enterprise.inject.Instance;`

This `handlers` variable will have all the implementations of `Handler` interface.

`javax.enterprise.inject.Instance` also implements the `Iterable` so you can iterate to it and call the required methods.

```
@Inject
Instance<Handler> handlers;

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public List<String> handle() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    handlers.forEach(handler -> list.add(handler.handle()));
    return list;
}
```